# Double click WPFNotifyIcon with Caliburn Micro

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to use [WPF NotifyIcon](http://www.hardcodet.net/projects/wpf-notifyicon) and [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) together. My end goal is that I double click on the icon in my system tray to restore my window from a minimized state. Feel free to tell me if the way I'm trying to go about it is totally wrong.

I can see that there is a `DoubleClickCommand` on the `TaskbarIcon` (I don't see any DoubleClick event, which I would actually be happy to use, if it were available). Normally when working with commands while using Caliburn Micro, I would simply create, say, a `Restore()` method and a `CanRestore` property which would automatically be called by a button named Restore. How would I go about hooking things up so that `Restore()` is called upon a double click on the icon in the system tray?

EDIT - As per gleng's suggestion, I have now added an attached event, but double clicking the icon in the system tray still seems to do nothing. Code below.

xaml -

```
<tb:TaskbarIcon cal:Message.Attach="[Event DoubleClick] = [Action Restore]" />
```

VM -

```
public void Restore()
{
    MessageBox.Show("moo"); // breakpoint on this line is never hit
}

public bool CanRestore
{
    get { return true; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<TaskbarIcon cal:Message.Attach="[Event TrayMouseDoubleClick] = [Action DoubleClickFunc]"/>
```

Notice that the event name is `TrayMouseDoubleClick` which I found by looking at the source code of the control, specifically the file named `TaskBarIcon.Declarations.cs`.

This file contains all dependency property definitions and routed events that are defined for the `TaskBarIcon` class.

Answer (score 1):

How about you create an attached event?

```
<TaskbarIcon cal:Message.Attach="[Event DoubleClick] = [Action DoubleClickFunc]"/>
```

Then in your view model you'll have:

```
public void DoubleClickFunc()
{
   // Your custom logic here
}
```

I've done this in the past and it works quite well.

Comment: This was one of the things I tried originally, but maybe I'm doing something wrong still? I've edited my question above with the code I tried.